# Let $\mathcal{C}$ be an open cover of $K \subset X$. If $z \in \overline{K}$ , does there exist $U \in \mathcal{C}$ such that $z\in U$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X, \tau)$ be a  topological space, $K \subset X$ and let $\mathcal{C}$ be an open cover of $K$. If $z \in \overline{K}$ , does there exist $U \in \mathcal{C}$ such that $z\in U$?

Reading a paper, I saw an argument that used the above fact for topological vector spaces. I imagine this is a known fact, however I am not so familiar with topological spaces. I am looking for a proof or maybe a reference of the above result.

Thank you!

Comment: Don't see why this would be true. Take $K$ to be an open interval in $\mathbb R$ and $\mathcal C$ to be the trivial cover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This claim is wrong. E.g. $K=(0,1)\subset X=\Bbb R,$ $\mathcal C=(K),$ and $z=0.$